# Insert images one by one, page by page, in Shape (ConvertToShape)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to populate a Word document with images obtained from a specific folder and insert them one by one page by page.

My code gives me the first part (getting images from a specific folder), but it fails miserably at placing them image by image, page by page. It ends up placing some images spaced out and others. For some reason I don't know, it adds several on top of each other at the end of the document.

I've tried everything, and the closest I've come is the code reproduced below. I'm also showing an image that gives you a better idea of the mess the images in the document are in.

For me, is important that work in Shape mode (not Inline!).

The code:

```vb
Sub Insert_Images_Bilder_Import() 
 
    Dim Path As String 
    Dim fs As Object 
    Dim ff As Variant 
    Dim Img As Variant 
    Dim i As Long 
    Dim fsize As Long 
    Dim Shp As shape 
    Dim Rng As Range 
 
    Path = "C:\Users\L\Pictures\" 
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Set ff = fs.GetFolder(Path).Files 
    i = 0 
    fsize = ff.count 
       
    With ActiveDocument 
    For Each Img In ff 
            Select Case Right(Img.Name, 4) 
                Case ".bmp", ".jpg", ".gif", ".png" 
                    i = i + 1 
                    Set Shp = ActiveDocument.shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=Img, _ 
                    LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Width:=CentimetersToPoints(18), Height:=CentimetersToPoints(25), Anchor:=Selection.Range) 
                                        
                    With Shp 
                        .LockAspectRatio = False 
                        .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin 
                        .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin 
                        .RelativeHorizontalSize = wdRelativeHorizontalSizeMargin 
                        .RelativeVerticalSize = wdRelativeVerticalSizeMargin 
                        .Left = wdShapeCenter 
                        .LeftRelative = wdShapePositionRelativeNone 
                        .Top = wdShapeTop 
                        .TopRelative = wdShapePositionRelativeNone 
                        .WidthRelative = wdShapeSizeRelativeNone 
                        .HeightRelative = wdShapeSizeRelativeNone 
                        .LockAnchor = False 
                        .LayoutInCell = True 
                        .WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = True 
                        .WrapFormat.Side = wdWrapBoth 
                        .WrapFormat.DistanceTop = MillimetersToPoints(0) 
                        .WrapFormat.DistanceBottom = MillimetersToPoints(0) 
                        .WrapFormat.DistanceLeft = MillimetersToPoints(120) 
                        .WrapFormat.DistanceRight = MillimetersToPoints(120) 
                        .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapTight 
                        .Line.Visible = True 
                        .Line.Style = msoLineSingle 
                        .Line.Weight = 0.5 
                        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(102, 51, 0) 
                                             
                    End With 
            
[Here begins my problem!]
        
                    Selection.TypeParagraph 
                    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapsEnd 
                    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak 
 

                End Select 
        Next 
         
    End With 
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

- Using `EndKey` to move the selection to the end of the doc

```vb
    With ActiveDocument
        For Each Img In ff
            Select Case Right(Img.Name, 4)
            Case ".bmp", ".jpg", ".gif", ".png"
                i = i + 1
                Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory  ' **change**
                Set Shp = ...
                With Shp 
                ' your code
                End With
                Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory  ' **change**
                Selection.TypeParagraph  ' **change**
            End Select
        Next
    End With
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Selection.EndKey method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.endkey?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158663161)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: Fantastic!!!

Thank you very much!!!